# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined Even JQuery included

Tags: jquery, html

I am getting this error even I have included JQuery in my page...

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined
```

The line is causing the error is

```
 $.post("infusionsoft/infusion_soft_interaction.php", 
   {customerName: 'customerName', customerEmail: 'customerEmail'},
 function(data) {
        alert(data);
    });
```

Here is the `HEAD` section of my page.

http://pastebin.com/xK8dWQ1U

Comment: It's a good practice to add your scripts at the end of the document, also have added this snippet inside document.ready() ?

Comment: have you used the ready function? `$(function(){ "your code here" })`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe the problem comes from the fact that you are using no-conflict mode for jQuery.

You need to reference it via `jQuery`.

```
jQuery.post("infusionsoft/infusion_soft_interaction.php", ...
```

or wrap your code with a function

```
(function($){
    $.post("infusionsoft/infusion_soft_interaction.php", ...
}(jQuery))
```

Comment: Yahooo ... thanks solved ... 

Can you please explain why  no-conflict  was causing this???

Comment: @user3709682 You are loading something called `/jquery/jquery-noconflict.js` :) I guess this code switches `jQuery.noConflict()` on. And noconflict mode is used when you for some reason don't want jQuery to use `$` as a shortcut.

Comment: In no-conflict file I have only this ... 

jQuery.noConflict();

Comment: @user3709682 Right this line causes jQuery not to use `$`. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/